# Phonegap Contacts - Error Displaying Phonenumbers

Tags: cordova, contacts, android-contacts

I'm working with phonegap, My actual code shows the names of each contact in my mobile phone but when I want to show the phone numbers shows me a "null". Some contacts don't have phone numbers, google contacts for example but I've tested only with some contacts which have phone number saved and doesen't work either !

The error exactyle is : "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null". I understand the error but I don't understand why show me this if I tested one contact which have phone number.

I'm following the official tutorial from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html#ContactField

**EDIT**
**CODE ADDED**

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    // specify contact search criteria
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter = "pepepe";      // empty search string returns all contacts
    options.multiple = true;  // return multiple results
    filter = ["displayName"]; // return contact.displayName field    

    // find contacts
    navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
}
```

**Could be the problem in filter var ?**

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {


for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
    document.write(contacts[i].displayName);
    tlf=contacts[i].phoneNumbers;
    try{
    document.write(contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value);
    }
    catch(err){
    window.alert(err);
    }
    if (tlf== null){
    document.write("No hi han telefons");
    }else{
    document.write(contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value);
    }
    /*
    for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
        document.write("Type: " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].type + "\n" + 
                "Value: "  + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value + "\n" + 
                "Preferred: "  + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].pref);
    }
    */
    document.write("<br/>");
}
```

};

**EDIT: It's very strange that always return null, if there are phone numners registered !**

Comment: Have you tried consol.log() the contacts object to see how it's formatted.  From there you should be able to know how to access the data.

Comment: window.alert(contacts) shows me [object Object],[object Object] and window.alert(contacts.phoneNumbers) shows me undefined

Comment: what version of phonegap are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using outdated documentation.  From the comments you're using version 3.x.  Here's the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts) on how to use it now.

It looks like what's different now is that you have to specify which fields you want to be able to use them.

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {
    alert('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts.');
};

function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
};

// find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter   = "Bob";
options.multiple = true;
var fields       = ["displayName", "name"]; //here you would add phoneNumbers
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

Or if you want to get all the fields the Documentation says:

> A contactFields value of  "*"  returns all contact fields.

Comment: I checked before look your answer but thanks a lot. Sometimes I can't see what I have in front of my eyes...

Comment: There is no conceivable way this will find any contact named "Bob" as your comment says.  What it will find is ALL records.

Answer (score 2):

hey just check for the object whether it is null or not before proceeding. This helped me get around that error.

Here is the check

if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers != null) 
{

.....................
......................

}